# Entity Framework not mapping some of my one to many relationships

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a question regarding Entity Framework. I created a database, then using the Entity Framework Power Tools using the Reverse Engineer Code First option to create some models of the database entities. The relationships produced were not what I was expecting.

In the DB, I have four tables: Work, WorkType, WorkCategory, Person. WorkType, WorkCategory and Person are all 1 to many relationships with the Work table, using foreign keys in the Work table.

The WorkType and WorkCategory relationship is fine, but the Work to Person relationship has been ignored.

I say this as there is no strongly typed virtual property called Person in the work.cs model class (as there is for WorkType and WorkCategory) and there is no relationship defined in the WorkMap.cs file (WorkType and WorkCategory relationships are defined).

Please could someone explain what I am missing? Thanks!

Work.cs model class that is generated:

```
public partial class Work
{
    public Work()
    {
        this.Comments = new List<Comment>();
        this.Files = new List<File>();
    }
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalInfo { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int WorkTypeId { get; set; }
    public int WorkCategoryId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual WorkCategory WorkCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual WorkType WorkType { get; set; }
}
```

workmap.cs mapping produced by the EF Power Tools:

```
public class WorkMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Work>
{
    public WorkMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.WorkId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(300);

        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(3000);

        this.Property(t => t.TechnicalInfo)
            .HasMaxLength(400);


        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.WorkCategory)
            .WithMany(t => t.Works)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.WorkCategoryId);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.WorkType)
            .WithMany(t => t.Works)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.WorkTypeId);

    }
}
```

SQL create scripts showing the relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [ReputationPoints] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkType](
    [WorkTypeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WorkTypeDesc] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkTypeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkCategory](
    [WorkCategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WorkCategoryDesc] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [WorkTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkCategoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Work](
    [WorkId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](3000) NOT NULL,
    [TechnicalInfo] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Work] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[File](
    [FileId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Filename] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Url] [varchar](3000) NULL,
    [WorkId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_File] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FileId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comment](
    [CommentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CommentText] [varchar](2000) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Comment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CommentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Work]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Work_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Work] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Work_Person]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Work]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Work_WorkCategory] FOREIGN KEY([WorkCategoryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[WorkCategory] ([WorkCategoryId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Work] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Work_WorkCategory]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Work]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Work_WorkType] FOREIGN KEY([WorkTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[WorkType] ([WorkTypeId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Work] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Work_WorkType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[File]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_File_Work] FOREIGN KEY([WorkId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Work] ([WorkId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[File] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_File_Work]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Comment_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Comment_Person]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Comment_Work] FOREIGN KEY([WorkId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Work] ([WorkId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Comment_Work]
GO
```

Comment: Which versions are you in? I can't repro this with the latest power tools, VS2012, EF 6 rc1. +1 for supplying the db create script.

Comment: @gert-arnold I am using VS2010 (more info below), MVC3, EF 5.0 (calls itself 4.4 in VS2010).

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel - Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel - Entity Framework Power Tools 1.0 - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU Service Pack 1